# Is there a way to create dynamic breadcrumbs in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have Angular 6 app with breadcrumbs which comes from the data in route. For example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: RootComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        data: {
           breadcrumb: "products"
        },
        children: [
         {
            path: ":id",
            component: ProductComponent,
            data: {
              breadcrumb: "product"
            }
         },
         {
           path: ":id/edit",
           component: ProductEditComponent,
           data: {
             breadcrumb: "edit"
           }
         }
        ] 
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

Is there a way to add custom information from the component in the breadcrumbs ? For example instead `products > edit` to have `products > salmon > edit`. I tried to add more data to the route from the component in ngOnInit function, but the problem is that the data hasn't arrived when the function is called, so the data is yet `undefined`.

My current logic for getting the breadcrumbs is something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB: string = "breadcrumb";

    //subscribe to the NavigationEnd event
    this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(event => {
      //set breadcrumbs
      let root: ActivatedRoute = this.activatedRoute.root;
      this.breadcrumbs = this.getBreadcrumbs(root);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Returns array of IBreadcrumb objects that represent the breadcrumb
   *
   * @class DetailComponent
   * @method getBreadcrumbs
   * @param {ActivateRoute} route
   * @param {string} url
   * @param {IBreadcrumb[]} breadcrumbs
   */
  private getBreadcrumbs(route: ActivatedRoute, url: string="", breadcrumbs: IBreadcrumb[]=[]): IBreadcrumb[] {
    const ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB: string = "breadcrumb";

    //get the child routes
    let children: ActivatedRoute[] = route.children;

    //return if there are no more children
    if (children.length === 0) {
      return breadcrumbs;
    }

    //iterate over each children
    for (let child of children) {
      //verify primary route
      if (child.outlet !== PRIMARY_OUTLET) {
        continue;
      }

      //verify the custom data property "breadcrumb" is specified on the route
      if (!child.snapshot.data.hasOwnProperty(ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB)) {
        return this.getBreadcrumbs(child, url, breadcrumbs);
      }

      //get the route's URL segment
      let routeURL: string = child.snapshot.url.map(segment => 
        segment.path).join("/");

      //append route URL to URL
      url += `/${routeURL}`;

      //add breadcrumb
      let breadcrumb: IBreadcrumb = {
        label: child.snapshot.data[ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB],
        params: child.snapshot.params,
        url: url
      };
      breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);

      //recursive
      return this.getBreadcrumbs(child, url, breadcrumbs);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ngAfterViewInit in your breadcrumb.ts.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      let root: ActivatedRoute = this.activeRouter.root;
      //console.log(this.activeRouter.snapshot.url);
      this.breadcrumbs = this.getBreadcrumbs(root);
    });
  }
```

And then in your component.ts,

```
  @ViewChild(BreadcrumbComponent) breadcrumbRef: BreadcrumbComponent; //reference to the breadcrumb

ngOnInit(){
  this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(
    res => { 
      this.breadcrumbRef.ngAfterViewInit()
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm a noob... I'm not understanding where to put the second block of code. The first block of code get me the breadcrumbs in view without the `Home /` portion. I suppose that would be because of the page refresh, we never visited the home page.

Comment: Although, when I click on another link after a page refresh, It adds the `Home /` back into the breadcrumbs

Comment: I suggest making the breadcrumb as a shared component for the entire project to use. And then at each component that requires breadcrumb, import the breadcrumb component. The second block of code should be in any of the other components that need breadcrumb.