# Build breadcrumbs on page refresh with Angular 7 Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a single component that relies on router events to generate breadcrumbs and display them in the browser. Now this module works great while you navigate the application.

However, if you refresh the page, you do not get any breadcrumbs until you visit a new new route by clicking on the href that leads to it.

How do I make this component generate breadcrumbs on page load as well?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd, PRIMARY_OUTLET } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth/auth.service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { filter, distinctUntilChanged, map, subscribeOn } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumb',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumb.component.html'
})

export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {


  public breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[];
  show: boolean = false;

  /**
  /*.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
 .distinctUntilChanged()
 .map(event =>  this.buildBreadCrumb(this.activatedRoute.root)); */

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, public authService: AuthService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) {
        this.show = true;
      } else {
        this.show = false;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let breadcrumb: Breadcrumb = {
      label: 'Home',
      url: 'dashboard'
    };

    this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(event => {
      //set breadcrumbs
      let root: ActivatedRoute = this.route.root;
      this.breadcrumbs = this.getBreadcrumbs(root);
       this.breadcrumbs = [breadcrumb, ...this.breadcrumbs];

    });

  }


  private getBreadcrumbs(route: ActivatedRoute, url: string = "", breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[] = []): Breadcrumb[] {
    const ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB: string = "breadcrumb";
    //get the child routes
    let children: ActivatedRoute[] = route.children;

    //return if there are no more children
    if (children.length === 0) {
      return breadcrumbs;
    }

    //iterate over each children
    for (let child of children) {
      //verify primary route
      if (child.outlet !== PRIMARY_OUTLET || child.snapshot.url.length==0) {
        continue;
      }

      //verify the custom data property "breadcrumb" is specified on the route
      if (!child.snapshot.data.hasOwnProperty(ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB)) {
        return this.getBreadcrumbs(child, url, breadcrumbs);
      }

      //get the route's URL segment
      let routeURL: string = child.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join("/");

      //append route URL to URL
      url += `/${routeURL}`;

      //add breadcrumb
      let breadcrumb: Breadcrumb = {
        label: child.snapshot.data[ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB],
        url: url
      };
      breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);

      //recursive
      return this.getBreadcrumbs(child, url, breadcrumbs);
    }
    return breadcrumbs;
  }



}

export interface Breadcrumb{
  label: string;
    url: string;
}
```

Comment: Does this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621525/is-there-a-way-to-create-dynamic-breadcrumbs-in-angular-6/54623148#54623148 help you?